# How to define an argument similar to --help or --version with argparse?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

In my command line program, I want to add an argument `--list-addons` that just prints the available addons in the program and exits (similar to what `--version` or `--help` in many programs usually do).

```
python main.py --list-addons
addon1
addon2
addon3
```

How can I do this while at the same time having a lot of other arguments defined? The `--list-addons` option cannot be used in conjunction with any other arguments.

Comment: I would adapt the Action class that version or help uses; look in the `argparse.py` file for `class _VersionAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the docs about writing a custom Action class.  Here's a simplification of the `_VersionAction` class, which displays a message and exits.

```
class ListAction(Action):
    # omit the custom __init__    
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        message = <format your list>
        parser.exit(message=message)
```